# How to get Facebook access token using Python library?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've found [this Library](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/) it seems it is the official one, then [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488913/how-to-obtain-a-user-access-token-in-python), but everytime i find an answer the half of it are links to [Facebook API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/) which talks about Javascript or PHP and how to extract it from links!

How do i make it on simple python script?

NB: what i realy dont understand, why using a library and cant extract `token` if we can use `urllib` and `regex` to extract informations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript and PHP can be used as web development languages. You need a web front end for the user to grant permission so that you can obtain the access token.

Rephrased: **You cannot obtain the access token programmatically, there must be manual user interaction**

In Python it will involve setting up a web server, for example a script to update feed using facepy

```
import web
from facepy import GraphAPI
from urlparse import parse_qs

url = ('/', 'index')

app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID"
app_secret = "APP_SECRET"
post_login_url = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"

user_data = web.input(code=None)

if not user_data.code:
    dialog_url = ( "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +
                               "client_id=" + app_id +
                               "&redirect_uri=" + post_login_url +
                               "&scope=publish_stream" )

    return "<script>top.location.href='" + dialog_url + "'</script>"
else:
    graph = GraphAPI()
    response = graph.get(
        path='oauth/access_token',
        client_id=app_id,
        client_secret=app_secret,
        redirect_uri=post_login_url,
        code=code
    )
    data = parse_qs(response)
    graph = GraphAPI(data['access_token'][0])
    graph.post(path = 'me/feed', message = 'Your message here')
```

Comment: ahhhh! that what i need! complete solution, just last question, `post_login_url` is the link i registred when making my facebook application (localhost:8888) ?

Comment: @Abdelouahab the above creates a webserver at local:8888 so I'm just redirecting back to local:8888 after authentication thus `top.location.href` (though the answer to your question is yes for this specific example)

Comment: juste about the `return` it should be removed because there is no function

Comment: @Abdelouahab This isn't really the whole script just snippets pushed together to give the basic gist, most of the code was in an index class, http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/publish-a-facebook-photo-in-python-the-basic-sauce/

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this helps anyone, but I was able to get an oauth_access_token by following this code.

```
from facepy import utils
app_id = 134134134134 # must be integer
app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
oath_access_token = utils.get_application_access_token(app_id, app_secret)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

here is a Gist i tried to make using `Tornado` since the answer uses `web.py`

https://gist.github.com/abdelouahabb/5647185

Comment: Hi, i'm not familiar with tornado and i'm having trouble understanding where should i put my access token, my app secret and my app ID, can you help me?