# cannot get facebook page data for some pages

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am generating new access token using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19781835/3104569).

Using access token, I can send request to facebook's graph api.

For example, I want to pull details of https://www.facebook.com/custtap. Then, this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/custtap?fields=name,about,emails&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE
```

This works fine, I get desired results. Similarly, it works fine for other pages that I don't have any access.

But, this way doesn't work for page(https://www.facebook.com/LatentView).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/LatentView?fields=name,about,emails&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE
```

This returns

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "C6DYVxvWZ91"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is access-restricted (page settings) in some way – that can f.e. be based on age, location, for alcohol-related content.

Therefor you need to either use a user access token for a user that is allowed to see the page, or a page access token (which requires admin access to the page to get.)

Everything you need to know is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens