# How to read the wall of a private Facebook Group through a stand-alone python script?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

We're making a game and for that game I need to 1) get all the messages in a private group's wall 2) parse the new messages since the last time I checked 3) other stuff not relevant.

I already wrote it, the problem is my access tokens expire from time to time. How can I get new access tokens from the python script ? This python script will be running for several weeks and I can't from time to time wake up in the middle of the night to go click in a dialog granting permissions to read that group's wall.

Also, I found this python code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058723/programmatically-getting-an-access-token-for-using-the-facebook-graph-api) and I was trying to use it to get the access tokens, but I'm clueless on the oauth_args:

```
def grabAccessToken ():
  print "grabbing access token..."
  oauth_args = dict(
    client_id     = "000000000000000",
    client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    redirect_uri  = 'http://domain.com/',
    scope         = "user_groups"
  )
  oauth_curl_cmd = [
    'curl',
    'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)
  ]
  oauth_response = subprocess.Popen(
    oauth_curl_cmd,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
  ).communicate()[0]

  print oauth_response
  try:
      oauth_access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(str(oauth_response))['access_token'][0]
      print "got access token: "+oauth_access_token
      return(oauth_access_token)
  except KeyError:
      return('ENOTOKEN')
```

It keeps responding "{"error":{"message":"Missing authorization Code","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}"

In short: How can a stand-alone Python script keep reading a Facebook Group Wall for a lot of time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In short: How can a stand-alone Python script keep reading a Facebook Group Wall for a lot of time ?

You can **not** get a new access token without user interaction. That’s the whole point of deprecating offline_access.

So you have to revisit your app to get a new token when the existing one expires.

I’d suggest storing your long-lived access token *and* it’s expiry date in your database, and then have your app send you an email in the background if that expiry date is approaching. Chose whatever timeframe you think is appropriate – a few days in advance, one or two weeks, whatever you like.

Comment: So how much time will these long-lived tokens last ? How do I request them ? Seems like the best option...