# How to connect to Facebook Graph API from Python using Requests if I do not need user access token?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I am trying to find the easiest way how to use Facebook Graph API using my favorite [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library. The problem is, all examples I found are about getting **user access token**, about redirects and user interaction.

All I need is only **application access token**. I do not handle any non-public data, so I need no user interaction and as my final app is supposed to be command-line script, no redirects are desired.

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058723/programmatically-getting-an-access-token-for-using-the-facebook-graph-api), but it seems to be everything but elegant. Moreover, I would prefer something using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) or [Requests-OAuth2](https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth2). Or maybe there is library for that? I found [Requests-Facebook](https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth2) and [Facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) (both Requests based), but again, all examples are with redirection, etc. Facepy does not handle authorization at all, it just accepts your token and it is up to you to get it somehow.

Could someone, please, provide a short, sane, working example how to get just the application access token?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123&client_secret=XXX')
access_token = r.text.split('=')[1]
print access_token
```

(using the correct values for `client_id` and `client_secret`) gives me something that looks like an access token.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a quick/small request, you can manually cut and paste the access token from here into you code: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Note: Unlike Richard Barnett's answer, you'll need to regenerate the code manually from the graph api explorer every time you use it.