# facebook get friends' birthdays using python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just wanted to get my friends' birthday on facebook using its python api

I tried the query in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ with "me/friends?fields=birthday", which works fine, but in my python code it says "GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I posted my code here:

```
import facebook

token = 'a token' # token omitted here, this is the same token when I use in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ 

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
fb = graph.request("me/friends?fields=birthday")
# while graph.request("me/friends") works well


print fb
```

someone helps?

Comment: You need to get a valid token, not your own randomly generated string. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611240/how-to-connect-to-facebook-graph-api-from-python-using-requests-if-i-do-not-need) suggests how.

Comment: Not a random token, I just omit it here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this works...

```
args = {'fields' : 'birthday,name' }
friends = graph.get_object("me/friends",**args)
```

quirkily

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked it a little and this works partially.

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
graph=GraphAPI('AccessToken')
friends=[]
friends= graph.get("me/friends?fields=birthday") 
print friends
```

However, it returns only some birthdays(returned just 3 of the 600+ friends I have).

Comment: < 0.5% coverage? Not really an answer, is it?

Comment: @mbs I think it is because of the privacy control in Facebook. I ran the same code in Facebook and got the same output.

Comment: I managed to get all birthdays using an older version of the API(v 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

You should supply ID there.There a same question.
looking for: 
[(OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096261/oauthexception-2500-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-informatio)

Comment: "me" actually works for graph.request("me/friends"), please see edits

Comment: or try to supply User ID.

Comment: If I use User ID instead of "me", it actually works for "$ID$/friends" but fails in request like "$ID$/friends?fields=birthday" and says "?" can not be recognized