# Error getting facebook friends who have app installed

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flask

I'm writing a Python app that is basically a RESTful server for a game, with Flask. But I'm having some issues with facebook-sdk.

Player logs in with facebook on the client game and send me the access token. I'm fetching user data and their friends who also play the game (to build a friendship relationship in my system). But there is a problem, when I try to fetch `me/friends?fields=installed` it always get me `facebook.GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` If I just query for `me/friends` it returns okay.

If I try querying these info directly from Graph API Explorer, it just works fine. But when I go to the python repl it returns the error. I'm trying this:

```
>>> graph = facebook.GraphAPI("[access-token]")
>>> graph.get_object("me/friends?fields=installed")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facebook.py", line 99, in get_object
    return self.request(id, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facebook.py", line 298, in request
    raise GraphAPIError(response)
facebook.GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I'm using the exact same access token as the one on the explorer.

Shouldn't I declare somewhere the current app-key or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Did you find the answer below of any use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use the `app-secret` and `app-id` in order to generate the Access Token. The access token that you'll obtain from this should solve the problem. You can use the following to generate an access token (1):

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

Since you are using Python, you can simple make a get request to the above URL in order to get the access token. This can be done by (2):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123&client_secret=XXX')
access_token = r.text.split('=')[1]
print access_token
```

You can even use any other python library to make this request.

---

Sources:

1. [Facebook Login - App Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens)
2. [Answer to "How to connect to Facebook Graph API from Python using
   Requests if I do not need user access token?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626170/1382832)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your permission that you included in authorization scene .. I think that reason why it says the token is invalid ..

check this document
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0
Hope it helps