# What can i do with App ID and App Secret?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to write a python script that posts automatically in my facebook page. After googling around, i found my self into Facebook Graph API docs. it says that i have to create a facebook app, so i did, and got my App ID and App Secret. Then i had to generate my app access token through this:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

Thereafter, I know that i should generate my user access token with manage_pages permissions, but all resources talking about how to do it with Graph API Explorer tool or through some web app sdks.

Can i post to my page with my app access token? if not, how can i get my user access token without methods mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

For posting to a Page you can either use a User Access Token (to post "as User") or a Page Access Token (to post "as Page"). The Facebook docs offer a large amount of information about the different Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

An App Token can only be used for specific things: Send Notifications (to Users who are authorized), Change App Settings, Read stuff from Facebook Pages, ...

What you probably want to use is an "Extended Page Token", it´s valid forever.

Here´s more information about the Access Tokens, the code is in PHP but there is a lot of important text too: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: It turns out that my app should be approved by facebook in order to use it for my own!

Comment: no, that is wrong. you only need approval for permissions if you want other people to use it. if you only create an app for yourself, no approval needed.

Comment: I always get this exception "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action". While i authorized my app to do all actions (permissions). Something wrong that i can't spot

Comment: put the used access token in the debugger and check if the permissions are set correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I tried the script here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058723/programmatically-getting-an-access-token-for-using-the-facebook-graph-api but still getting the same error. plus, can't get any user access token!